# create variables in python with available data

Tags: python

I have read a data like this:

```
import numpy as np
arr=n.loadtext("data/za.csv",delimeter=",")
display(arr)
```

Now the display looks like this:

```
array([[5.0e+01,1.8e+00,1.6e+00,1.75+e00],
       [4.8e+01,1.77e+00,1.63e+00,1.75+e00],
       [5.5e+01,1.8e+00,1.6e+00,1.75+e00],
       ...,
       [5.0e+01,1.8e+00,1.6e+00,1.75+e00],
       [4.8e+01,1.77e+00,1.63e+00,1.75+e00],
       [5.0e+01,1.8e+00,1.6e+00,1.75+e00]])
```

Now I would like to give this variables to this array

the first ist weight of person
second is height of person
third is height of mother
fourth is height of father

Now I would like to now how can I create this variables that representin the columns?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you would like to be able to give the array columns some names? You might want to have a look at `pandas.DataFrame` which does essentially this. Alternatively, you could extract a single column into a new variable, e.g. `weights = arr[:,0]`

Comment: yes, that's what I want give array columns some names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. install pandas library
2. import pandas as pd
3. use pd.read_csv("data/za.csv", columns= ["height", "weight", "etc"]) for read the data
   hope you get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As it has already been advised, you may use `pandas.read_csv` for the purpose as per below:

```
df = pd.read_csv(**{
    'filepath_or_buffer': "data/za.csv",
    'header': None,
    'names': ('weight_of_person', 'height_of_person', 'height_of_mother', 'height_of_father'),
})
```